# Choose value for Regarding field in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Mobile Express

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

I created a custom activity entity that should only be viewable in Mobile Express (ME). I could adapt the queries for all the views in CRM Online to exclude the entities with the type equal to my custom entity, but that's a bit of a tedious job.

Is there another way to set, on a higher level maybe, to exclude this custom entity from all **Activity** views?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, the only way to exclude the custom `activity` from and include all the other `activity`s in your `Activity` views is to alter the views' underlying `fetchXml`, either manually or by looping through the `SavedQuery` entity (see below), to make sure the view doesn't reference the `activity`. There's no flag that you can put in to stop your custom `activity` from showing up in any particular `activity` view; you need to alter *all* views to have this reflected (unless, of course, your custom `entity` is not an `activity` at all).

```cs
//using System.Xml.Linq;
//your list of activity entities excluding the special custom activity
string activityList = "<condition attribute=\"activitytypecode\" operator=\"in\"><value>4401</value><value>4204</value><value>10058</value></condition>"; 
XElement newFilter = XElement.Parse(activityList);

var sq = from q in xsc.SavedQuerySet
         where q.ReturnedTypeCode == ActivityPointer.EntityLogicalName
         select new
         {
             fetchXml = q.FetchXml
             , queryId = q.SavedQueryId
             , queryName = q.Name
         };

foreach (var q in sq)
{
    //do your xml parsing
    XElement xml = XElement.Parse(q.fetchXml);

    if (!xml.Elements("entity")
            .Elements("filter").Where(x => x.Attributes("type").Single().Value == "and").Any())
    {
        xml.Elements("entity").Single().Add(XElement.Parse("<filter type=\"and\"></filter>"));    
    }

    //some level of validation
    if (!xml.Elements("entity")
            .Elements("filter")
            .Where(x => x.Attributes("type").Single().Value == "and")
            .Single().Elements("condition")
            .Where(x => x.Attributes("attribute")
            .Single().Value == "activitytypecode")
            .Where(x => x.Attributes("operator")
            .Single().Value == "in").Any())
    {
        xml.Elements("entity")
            .Elements("filter")
            .Where(x => x.Attributes("type")
            .Single().Value == "and")
            .Single().Add(newFilter);

        SavedQuery query = new SavedQuery();
        query.SavedQueryId = q.queryId;
        query.FetchXml = xml.ToString();
        service.Update(query);
    }
}
```

You'll need to publish after this to see your changes stick.